# XNA Touch Location

Tags: xna

I am making a bubble wrap game. The kind where you press the bubbles to pop them and they unpop after a little bit. it all works fine, the bubbles pop and unpop as planned. There is one issue though. Whenever I click and drag the bubbles still pop. Is there a way to get them not to pop when i click and drag? Here is my code for the touch location.

```
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touches)
            {
                if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                {
                    if (rectangle.Contains((int)tl.Position.X, (int)tl.Position.Y))
                    {
                        popLocationX = (int)tl.Position.X;
                        popLocationY = (int)tl.Position.Y;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do, I use this on my main menu but should be able to transfer over.

Have these added in:

```
    MouseState mouse;
    public float mouseDelay = 0.01f;
    public float mouseTime = 0.0f;
    public bool mouseActive = true;
    public bool mouseUsed = false;
    public string mouseOn = "None";
    public Vector2 mouseLocation;
```

- mouse helps find the location of the mouse.
- mouseDelay will stop the the repeating when you have the mouse in the pressed position.
- mouseTime will say hey, if I am greater than mouseDelay mouse can be used again.
- mouseActive will say if it is pressed or not. If mouse is pressed mouseActive is false.
- mouseUsed will see if it is ever used. If the mouse is not clicking on anything but the background then it will be false. If true that means it was used to do something.
- mouseOn is used in my main menu to say you pressing on options? Make `mouseOn = "Options";`and go to it.
- The mouseLocation holds where the mouse is.

All this in mind putting this all together will help you with your goal of not having the mouse used when it is already pressed.

In update:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (this.IsMouseVisible == true)
        {
            MouseActive(gameTime);
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

I have if mouse is visible to stop the process from repeating when the mouse is not there (less processing power).

**Remember this was made for a main menu if you want to make this for a game you need to mess around with it a little.**

```
    void MouseActive(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        mouseTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        mouseLocation = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                break;
            case GameStates.Options:
                break;
            case GameStates.Credits:
                break;
        }

        if (mouseOn != "None")
        {
            mouseUsed = true;

            switch (gameState)
            {
                case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                    if (mouseOn == "Play")
                    {
                    }
                    if (mouseOn == "Quit")
                        this.Exit();
                    if (mouseOn == "Options")
                        gameState = GameStates.Options;
                    if (mouseOn == "Title")
                    {
                    }
                    break;
                case GameStates.Options:
                    break;
                case GameStates.Credits:
                    break;
            }

            mouseOn = "None";
        }

        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            mouseTime = 0.0f;
            mouseActive = false;
        }

        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && mouseTime > mouseDelay)
        {
            mouseActive = true;
            mouseUsed = false;
        }
    }
```

**All the code from above is going to be in the main class**

Here is a class named `TitleScreen.cs` were I use the images on the TitlesScreen and the mouse from the main class:

You first need to Initialize the thing so add this method in TitleScreen:

```
    Game1 game1;

    public void Initialize(Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;
    }
```

**You need to add in an Initializer to the Main class(Game1.cs)**

```
TitleScreen titlescreen;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        titlescreen = new TitleScreen();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        titlescreen.Initialize(this);

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Then for the final step you add Update to the TitleScreen:

```
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game1.mouseUsed == false && game1.mouseActive == true)
        {
            if (play.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Play";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (title.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Title";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (options.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Options";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (quit.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Quit";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**You also need to add this to the Update in the main class**

```
titlescreen.Update(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with touch yet, but the logic should be similar across all input methods.

I would create a variable to store the old TouchLocationState. That way, you can check if the user is clicking and dragging. For example:

```
//TODO: instantiate this
TouchLocationState oldTLState; 

...

// This condition will only be true when the user clicks once, dragging will return false as the oldTLSTate is not released
if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed && oldTLState.State == TouchLocationState.Released)
{
    if (rectangle.Contains((int)tl.Position.X, (int)tl.Position.Y))
    {
        popLocationX = (int)tl.Position.X;
        popLocationY = (int)tl.Position.Y;
    }
}

//At the end of the Update() method, update oldTLState with the current state
oldTLState = tl;
```